# Here Javascript API example CORS errors

Tags: here-api

Just getting started with here. I've tried the javascript sample and getting cors error. My test url is https://fleetcom511.com/all_drivers_new.php

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.11.1&apikey=xxxxx' from origin 'http://fleetcom511.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
mapsjs-core.js:41 GET https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/info?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.11.1&apikey=xxxxx net::ERR_FAILED
d @ mapsjs-core.js:41
Lc @ mapsjs-core.js:42
application/json @ mapsjs-core.js:75
jf.qj @ mapsjs-core.js:74
(anonymous) @ mapsjs-core.js:52
(anonymous) @ mapsjs-core.js:52
$d.b @ mapsjs-core.js:52
$d.add @ mapsjs-core.js:51
Xd @ mapsjs-core.js:51
jf @ mapsjs-core.js:74
ip @ VM152:49
dp @ VM152:48
X.qb @ VM152:45
X.yj @ VM152:50
X.Ug @ VM152:60
(anonymous) @ all_drivers_new.php:50
all_drivers_new.php:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc/13/4096/4096/omv?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.11.1&apikey=xxxxxx' from origin 'http://fleetcom511.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
mapsjs-core.js:77 GET https://vector.hereapi.com/v2/vectortiles/base/mc/13/4096/4096/omv?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.11.1&apikey=xxxxx net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: You shouldn't be hitting that API from the client, you'll leak your key to your users.

Comment: leaking apikey is not a problem as you have an option to add domain whitelist.

Comment: Added relevant tag

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells where is the problem: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

You should enable CORS on your server. I don't know what type of server you use, but if it's apache, then this article should help: https://tecadmin.net/enable-cors-apache/